# Is there any way to download or install self signed root CA certificate in many browsers automatically

Tags: windows, ssl, web-server, ssl-certificate

Is there any way to download or install self signed root CA certificate in many browsers automatically.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you are trying to do. You have an Apache server on each workstation, and want each of them to get a certificate?

Comment: What control do you have over these servers? What tools could you use on them? What would your ideal solution look like?

Comment: I have only single server with multiple domain hosted on it.
Users are using Windows (XP/7).
I have my self signed certificate for each domain and root CA certificate.
My ideal solution will be:

when users will connect to web site first time my root CA certificate will automatically get download in there browser, so that browser will not show un-trusted certificate. OR some other way  so that I do not have to install / download root CA certificate on each work station manually.

Comment: So simply put, you want a method for your untrusted CA certificate to automatically be added to the chain of trusted root CA's? That's counter to the whole purpose of the CA trust and simply not going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the Windows workstations are in the same Active Directory domain use you can use a policy or the public key services to manage CA certificates and have the new one deployed automatically.

If you don't have control over the workstations the easiest is to simply buy an commercially signed certificate, with a bit of google-fu you can find them cheaply at just a couple of US$. That saves you the hassle of explaining that despite the browser warnings your server is secure, nor do you have to explain how to install a CA-certificate.